# how to create an exception for an object in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to throw an exception in Node.js with an object. But I don't know how to customize the return class.

Example:

```
class BusinessError extends Error {
  constructor(code, status, message) {
    super(message);
    this.code = code;
    this.name = 'Error';
    this.status = status;
  }
}

const error = {
 code: '001',
 status: 500,
 message: 'Error',
}

throw new BusinessError(error.code, error.status, error.message);
```

But, the other attributes do not appear in the return.

Ex:

{
    "message": "TypeError: foo is not a function"
}

But, i wanted it to be like this

{
    "message": "TypeError: foo is not a function",
    "code": 'X-100',
    "status": 500
}

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor doesn't accept an object but you instantiated `BusinessError` with an object. You could try destructuring the object in the class constructor like so

```js
class BusinessError extends Error {
  constructor({ code, status, message }) {
    super(message);
    this.name = 'BusinessError';
    this.status = status;
  }
}

const error = {
 code: '001',
 status: 500,
 message: 'This is an Error',
}

throw new BusinessError(error);
```

Comment: thanks, but using destructuring this way doesn't work

Comment: @MatheusAlmeida you sure?

Comment: The original code doesn't instantiate with an object like the answer suggests, but changing it to do so like with this code is a good solution.